# SQL Server with inner join returning more results than expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    us.userid, 
    us.username, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.created, 101) AS LastLoginDate 
FROM
    users us 
INNER JOIN 
    session s ON us.userid = s.userid 
WHERE  
    supergroupid = 145577 
ORDER BY 
    us.userid DESC
```

Now, since there are multiple session entries in the session table per user, I'm getting multiple (duplicate) results per user.

How can I get only the most recent s.created entry in the session table per user, only one entry along with the other data from the users table?

Comment: Google for "TOP N per group"  solutions for SQL Server,

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked and answered hundreds of times. But it was easier to code a solution than find a duplicate. Also, you really should not format your date in your query. That should be done in the presentation layer.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT us.userId, us.userName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),s.created, 101) as LastLoginDate
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by us.userId order by s.created desc)
      FROM users us
    inner join session s 
      on us.userId = s.userId
      where superGroupId = 145577
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
order by x.userid desc
```

Comment: It is probably better for Stack Overflow if we can find a duplicate than spoon-feed an answer `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer feel free to go find any of the duplicates and mark this question as a possible duplicate. This is such a simple question it was far easier to write out the query than look for any of the hundreds and hundreds of duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was making the wider point, which is that if you give an answer where you know a duplicate exists, it may teach question authors that they can get their answer by posting an unresearched question. Site janitors (voters, editors, etc) would rather have less work to do, so if you don't personally wish to find a duplicate (which I agree is annoying work) then it may be best not to answer.

Comment: (I appreciate this might be hard in the `sql` tag, where there's also a FGITW problem, but...)

Comment: @halfer if we all followed that nobody would answer any more questions. Seriously, there is nothing new in any question under this tag posted in the last couple years that hasn't been answered already. And until the next version is released the only questions allowed by this narrow philosophy would be the first question about new features.

Comment: I see what you mean, but maybe that would be too strict an interpretation. The problem here seems to be a lack of research, so perhaps it would be best to refrain from answering where there is a duplicate _and_ the OP does not appear to have made any personal effort? I think there is some value in walking question authors through a learning process where there is evidence of effort (and where the OP might struggle to apply possible duplicates).

Comment: @halfer not sure why you decided to choose my answer as the one to criticize the person answering for answering. There are six other valid answers here too. Every question about sql server is a duplicate and maybe one in ten questions don't show much, if any, research. I have now spent far more time and effort defending my decision to post an answer than the original answer took to write. I just don't understand your issue with my decision to post an answer.

Comment: Hi Sean - I am most keen to answer that objection. The answer is that yours is the only one that acknowledges the post as a duplicate.

Comment: @halfer what is your point? To split hairs? To demonstrate how wrong it was of me to answer a question? Do you honestly think that Gordon Linoff doesn't think this is a duplicate? You seem to want to belittle me for being helpful and I just don't understand what your point is. Would it bother you less if I just posted the answer and didn't state that it was a duplicate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193357/discussion-between-halfer-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 0):

I think a Group By with a Max() on the date would work:

```
SELECT us.userId, us.userName, MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),s.created, 101)) as LastLoginDate
  FROM users us
inner join session s 
  on us.userId = s.userId
  where superGroupId = 145577
  group by us.userId, us.userName
  order by us.userid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a subquery which returns the most recent session for each user and join on that like so:

```
SELECT us.userId, us.userName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),s.created, 101) as LastLoginDate
FROM users us
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.userId, s.created, ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY s.userId ORDER BY s.created DESC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM session AS s


) s 
  on us.userId = s.userId
  where superGroupId = 145577 AND s.[RowNum] = 1
  order by us.userid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date/time of the most recent session, use `max()`.  But *before* the conversion to a string!

```
select us.userId, us.userName, convert(varchar(10), max(s.created), 101) as LastLoginDate
from users us inner join
     session s 
     on us.userId = s.userId
where superGroupId = 145577
group by us.userid, us.userName;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
SELECT userId, MAX(created) as LastLoginDate
FROM session
GROUP BY userId
```

you get the last login date for each user.
Then join it to the table `users`:

```
SELECT us.userId, us.userName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.LastLoginDate, 101) as LastLoginDate
FROM users us INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userId, MAX(created) as LastLoginDate
    FROM session
    GROUP BY userId 
) s on s.userId = us.userId 
WHERE superGroupId = 145577
ORDER BY us.userid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mentioned it yet, I really like using a common table expression (CTE) which I think helps with readability.

```
;WITH ctelastlogin (userid, lastlogindate) 
     AS (SELECT userid, 
                Max(created) 
         FROM   session 
         GROUP  BY userid) 
SELECT us.userid, 
       us.username, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cte.lastlogindate, 101) AS LastLoginDate 
FROM   users us 
       INNER JOIN ctelastlogin cte 
               ON cte.userid = us.userid 
WHERE  supergroupid = 145577 
ORDER  BY us.userid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `rank` each session and then filter on the latest one.

Something like...

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY US.USERID ORDER BY LASTLOGINDATE DESC) RNK
)
WHERE RNK = 1
```